# How long does it take to generate large prime numbers?

Tags: cryptography, arbitrary-precision

Using a C implementation of bigint without any assembly, SSE etc.
running on a 2ghz dual core pentium laptop; what is
the average time that one should expect a prime number to
be created in?

Is it normal for primes which are greater than 512 bits to
take 30 seconds?

What about 2048, 4096 bits etc.?

From security stackexchange [question 56214](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56214/5121)

> I recently generated some custom Diffie-Hellman parameters which are basically just long (in the below case 4096 bit) primes.
> As the generation took roughly 2 hours it cannot be something that is >generated on the fly........

Is this typical ? - 2 hours to generate a 4096 bit key ...

Comment: Well, openssl should handle 2048 bit key generation within a second. But that doesn't it self tell, where's the optimization. Is it low level (assembler) or higher level (using better algorithms -- i.e. less complex operations). A naive primality test would be run for 100 or 200 candidates (skipping perhaps just even candidates); A better algorithm would make a sieve using bignum % (prod_of_small_primes) to prune out 95% of the other candidates.

Comment: Is there a page which shows benchmarks for prime generation with and without asm optimizations ? I've read that it might not be so uncommon to wait minutes to generate a key with a length of more than 2048 bits..

Comment: No, this question is meaningless. Assembler optimization is just one stage in making prime generation faster. Another is to add more cores hunting for `prime_candidate + 2*n`, which should scale almost N-fold. Yet another is to prune the candidates to `candidate + index[n]`, yet another to rearrange the miller-rabin or another primality test routine to use the optimal set of primitive bignum operations.

Comment: Diffie-Hellman-Primes are not "normal" primes but have to fulfill special requirements; take a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/54367/34179

Comment: Note that generating safe primes for DH parameters typically requires a very large number of primes to be tested for safety. For a 4096-bit set, typically millions of primes will have to be generated and tested.

Comment: I just created a custom Diffie Hellmann parameters with 4096 and it said "this is going to take a long time." it took about 5 mins

Answer (score 6):

No, 4 hours are definitely not typical.

Generation of large random primes depends on the following:

1. the speed and entropy within the random number generator
2. the used algorithm to test the candidates for primality
3. the implementation
4. and luck

The random number generator used is very important. Especially for long term keys it may be that you require a random bit generator that contains a large amount of entropy. This can be achieved by accessing e.g. `/dev/random` on linux operating systems, for instance. There is one unfortunate problem: `/dev/random` may block until sufficient entropy is gathered. Depending on the system that can be very fast or very very slow.

Now, the second is the algorithm. When generating new DH *parameters* then often a method to generate a so called *safe prime* is usually used. Now generating safe primes is much much harder than generating a number that is probable prime. However, that prime is only used for the DH parameters *not the key pair itself*. So generating a safe prime is generally not needed; you can simply used a set of pre-calculated or even *named* parameters.

The implementation can make a bit of a difference as well. Although it won't change the *order* of complexity, it may still influence the result if the implementation is a thousand times slower than a fast implementation. These kind of differences are not unheard of within cryptography; a slow, interpreted language may be much slower than a hardware accelerated version, or a version directly running using vector instructions of the CPU or indeed GPU.

Furthermore, the only way to see if a number is prime is to test the number. There is no deterministic method of just generating primes. The problem with that is that although there are many, many primes available, it can still take a long time to find one. This is where the luck factor comes in: it could be that the first number you test is prime, but it can also be that you run through oodles of numbers before finding one. So in the end the runtime of the procedure is indeterministic.

---

For a C program, generating a safe prime of 4096 bits in over 2 hours seems a bit much. However, if it runs a very old CPU, without any SSE, it would not necessarily mean that anything is fundamentally wrong. However, taking 30 seconds for a 512 bit prime is *very long*. OpenSSL command line takes only between 0.015 (lucky) and 1.5 (unlucky) seconds on my laptop (but that's a Core i7).

---

Notes:

- RSA generally requires two primes that are half the key size, and these are usually not safe primes. So generating a DH key pair (with new parameters) will take *much* longer than generating an RSA key pair of the same size.
- If possible try to use predefined DH parameters. Unfortunately the `openssl` command line doesn't seem to support named DH parameters; this is only supported for DSA key pairs.
- If you want speed, try Elliptic Curve DH with predefined parameters. Generating a key is almost as fast as just generating 256 random bits (for the P-256 curve, for instance). And until Quantum Crypto comes off age, those keys will be much stronger than DH keys on top of it.

Comment: /dev/random is non blocking since Linux 5.6 (after that answer was written). For all purpose it's now indistinguishable from /dev/urandom. See https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200131204924.GA455123@mit.edu/